# Do I need comma here?

Tags: пунктуация

Каждый человек живет в определённом(,) созданном им мире.

Comment: I would say, that if the first adjective, "определённый", pertains to the standalone word "мир", then you need a comma, since you are talking about "мир", which is "определённый" and "созданный им". If the first adjective pertains to the subject and the second adjective (or whatever is the proper name for this, probably the past participle), that is "созданный им мир", which is "определенный", then you don't need a comma. In speech the variant without a comma usually would be pronounced without a pause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

мире (каком?) определённом
мире (каком?) созданном им (созданном (кем?) им)

Т.е. это обычное прилагательное — `определённом` и причастие с зависимым словом (причастный оборот) `созданном им`. Причём определение и причастный оборот являются однородными членами.

Правила русского языка в данном случае таковы:

- причастный оборот (сам по себе) перед определяемым словом не выделяется запятыми (хотя после определяемого слова выделяется)

  > Каждый человек живет в созданном им мире.
  >   Каждый человек живет в мире, созданном им.
- если есть не только причастный оборот, но и прилагательное, то всё зависит от их порядка:

  - если причастный оборот разрывает более сильную связь "прилагательное-существительное" то запятая, соединяющая однородные прилагательное и причастный оборот, нужна:

    > Каждый человек живет в определённом, созданном им мире.
    >   Даже старые, серыми лишаями покрытые ветви деревьев зашептали о прошлых днях (М. Г.)
    >   Нет, не только во сне плачут пожилые, поседевшие за годы войны мужчины
  - Однако если причастный оборот стоит перед прилагательным, то запятая уже не нужна:

    > Каждый человек живет в созданном им определённом мире.
    >   Каждый раз появлялась и снова тонула в кромешном мраке припавшая к широким балкам степная станица (Пауст.);
    >   Сергей увидел плавающие в воздухе белые листки тетрадки (Вороб.).

Источник: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=110

Answer (score 1):

Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится(Розенталь)

> Каждый человек живет в определенном, созданном им мире.

Созданном им – пояснение предыдущего определения (определенном).